# Groovy XmlSlurper with Parallel Operation

Tags: groovy, xmlslurper, gpars

I am parsing some rss xml feed and need to expand some urls in the description field.

Now my code is written as

```
items.collect {
    it.description = FullText.expand(it.description)
    return it
}
```

In this case, the urls inside are requested one by one, making its process very slow.

So I want to do something like

```
items.collectParallel {
    it.description = FullText.expand(it.description)
    return it
}
```

But instead I get the error message：

`groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChildren.collectParallel() is applicable for argument types`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `items.collectParallel` block needs to be surrounded by a `GParsPool.withPool` block to have the `collectParallel` and other GPars methods be available, like:

```
import static groovyx.gpars.GParsPool.withPool

// ...

withPool {
    items.collectParallel {
        it.description = FullText.expand(it.description)
        return it
    }
}
```